# Transform with XSLT in a Grails Service

Tags: grails, xslt

I'd like to write a service in my grails web app to apply an xslt to some xml.  The following code throws a *java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1*:

```
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource

class RdfService {

    static transactional = false

 def transform(url){
  def String wsdl= url.toString().toURL().text
  def File xslt= new File("lib/SAWSDL_GRDDL.xsl")
  def TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
  def Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new FileReader(xslt)))
  def StringWriter out= new StringWriter()
  transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(wsdl)), new StreamResult(out))
  println out
 }
}
```

However, when I test the following similar code with the same values, I get the desired results:

```
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource



def xml= new File("data/wsdl/EtaService.wsdl").text
def xslt= new File("data/SAWSDL_GRDDL.xsl")
def factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
def transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new FileReader(xslt)))
def out= new StringWriter()
transformer.transform( new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)), 
        new StreamResult(out))
println out
```

My code was originally strived to be a bit more efficient, but at this point I'm just trying to get the thing to work :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a hack, but I found out if i removed the XML tag, in the document it would process it appropriately.

```
wsdl = wsdl.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '')
```

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work, but it (somehow) lead me to what might be the correct solution.  In a different environment, I was able to get the transform to work because I had the saxon9he.jar file in my build path.  So I just added that jar to my lib directory, and everything is swimming as it should.  Thanks for the help!